# Can't do git pull due to 401

Tags: linux, git, ssh, centos

On a server I faced with an issue:

```
$ git pull origin branch1:branch1
Password: 
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://123@bitbucket.org/123/456.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

The web site isn't mine but I'm working on it. I know the credentials: user login and password and login and password for ssh access. I provided the password of the user I was logged in by. And it seemed it turned out to be wrong, so it asked me about some other password. Which one?

Comment: what is branch1:branch1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it asked me about some other password. Which one?

With an url like https://123@bitbucket.org, it is asking you about the password of the account 123 on bitbucket (nothing to do with ssh passphrase).